# CoreOS cloud config not creating user

Tags: amazon-web-services, coreos

The template does not generate the bamboo user that I have set up in the cloud config. I ssh into my cluster and see cat /etc/passwd but I don't see that user. What might be going wrong?

```js
        {
          "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
          "Description": "CoreOS on EC2: http://coreos.com/docs/running-coreos/cloud-providers/ec2/",
          "Mappings" : {
              "RegionMap" : {
    
                  "us-west-2" : {
                      "AMI" : "ami-06af7f66"
                  }
              }
          },
          "Parameters": {
            "InstanceType" : {
              "Description" : "EC2 HVM instance type (m3.medium, etc).",
              "Type" : "String",
              "Default" : "t2.small",
              "AllowedValues" : [ "t2.micro", "m3.medium", "i2.4xlarge", "i2.8xlarge", "r3.large", "r3.xlarge", "r3.2xlarge","r3.4xlarge", "r3.8xlarge", "t2.micro", "t2.small", "t2.medium" ],
              "ConstraintDescription" : "Must be a valid EC2 HVM instance type."
            },
            "myVPC": {
                "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
                "Description": "The VPC Id where the instances will be deployed into."
            },
            "SecurityGroupId":{
              "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>",
              "Description": "Security group to launch instances into."
            },
            "SubnetId":{
              "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>",
              "Description": "VPC group to launch instances into."
            },
            "ClusterSize": {
              "Default": "3",
              "MinValue": "3",
              "MaxValue": "12",
              "Description": "Number of nodes in cluster (3-12).",
              "Type": "Number"
            },
            "DiscoveryURL": {
              "Description": "An unique etcd cluster discovery URL. Grab a new token from https://discovery.etcd.io/new?size=<your cluster size>",
              "Type": "String"
            },
            "AdvertisedIPAddress": {
              "Description": "Use 'private' if your etcd cluster is within one region or 'public' if it spans regions or cloud providers.",
              "Default": "private",
              "AllowedValues": ["private", "public"],
              "Type": "String"
            },
            "KeyPair" : {
              "Description" : "The name of an EC2 Key Pair to allow SSH access to the instance.",
              "Type" : "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName"
            }
          },
          "Resources": {
            "CoreOSServerAutoScale": {
              "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
              "Properties": {
                "LaunchConfigurationName": {"Ref": "CoreOSServerLaunchConfig"},
                "VPCZoneIdentifier": {"Ref":"SubnetId"},
                "MinSize": "3",
                "MaxSize": "12",
                "DesiredCapacity": {"Ref": "ClusterSize"},
                "Tags": [
                    {"Key": "Name", "Value": { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" }, "PropagateAtLaunch": true}
                ]
              }
            },
    
            "CoreOSServerLaunchConfig": {
              "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
              "Properties": {
                "ImageId" : { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "RegionMap", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "AMI" ]},
                "InstanceType": {"Ref": "InstanceType"},
                "KeyName": {"Ref": "KeyPair"},
                "SecurityGroups": {"Ref": "SecurityGroupId"},
                "UserData" : { "Fn::Base64":
                  { "Fn::Join": [ "", [
                    "#cloud-config\n\n",
                    "  users:\n",
                    "    - name: bamboo\n",
                    "      groups:\n",
                    "        - sudo\n",
                    "        - docker\n",
                    "        - fleet\n",
                    "        - systemd\n",
                    "        - wheel\n",
                    "        - bamboo\n",
                    "      ssh-authorized-keys:\n",
                    "        - ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDKT3QjGuTD4sdBfKZZm1cOz2gXBH546vGizsDGf3LEQC63QduU1CPQBvTG742H5yVix7y+qvZPTYlvQ1ysK6ezhbGeu+lT0WoI8YT4x2Pqe/F40WGn/SMv3ckELQhKH3gp9HC1z/ITxYVgTksKGGXgNO6G8w8J+XaC1hyYntyOz531GAly9szCxtPQJQCz1fS3fdjSPEM+7TyuwH240S/Aa0R0XGUt24xH4zyifmUjrvGq4AaHIFUyWO3XnEc/3kdA2uUQlV/2o7z9xE0WhYPWm2oReHXNuoOCQutTCYwNKaTI+Y/vGtGxsCmIQWVoY4Afg2nL0MQ1Mnfw3DddQJvB cmbuild@bamboo_agent_fleetctl \n",
                    "coreos:\n",
                    "  etcd2:\n",
                    "    discovery: ", { "Ref": "DiscoveryURL" }, "\n",
                    "    advertise-client-urls: http://$", { "Ref": "AdvertisedIPAddress" }, "_ipv4:2379\n",
                    "    initial-advertise-peer-urls: http://$", { "Ref": "AdvertisedIPAddress" }, "_ipv4:2380\n",
                    "    listen-client-urls: http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001\n",
                    "    listen-peer-urls: http://$", { "Ref": "AdvertisedIPAddress" }, "_ipv4:2380\n",
                    "  units:\n",
                    "    - name: etcd2.service\n",
                    "      command: start\n",
                    "    - name: fleet.service\n",
                    "      command: start\n"
                      ] ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

The cluster is generated and works well but I don't see that user. Is there a place I can see logs for why the user generation did not occur?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your actual question, you can see the logs of what happened with the cloud config using [`journalctl --identifier=coreos-cloudinit`](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/cloud-config.html)

You can also validate your cloud-config using the [online validator](https://coreos.com/validate/) or by running `coreos-cloudinit -validate` on your CoreOS machine.

However, taking a look at your config it seems that you have over-indented the [`users` block](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/cloud-config.html#users).

The following should work:

```
#cloud-config
users:
  - name: bamboo
    groups:
      - sudo
      - docker
      - fleet
      - systemd
      - wheel
      - bamboo
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa <RSA Public Key> cmbuild@bamboo_agent_fleetctl 
coreos:
  etcd2:
    discovery:  {Ref":DiscoveryURL" },
    advertise-client-urls: http://$ {Ref":AdvertisedIPAddress" },_ipv4:2379
    initial-advertise-peer-urls: http://$ {Ref":AdvertisedIPAddress" },_ipv4:2380
    listen-client-urls: http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001
    listen-peer-urls: http://$ {Ref":AdvertisedIPAddress" },_ipv4:2380
  units:
    - name: etcd2.service
      command: start
    - name: fleet.service
      command: start
```